# Read files in Python based on their semantic numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames, python-os, listdir

I'm trying to iterate over files in a directory using the following command in python 3.6:

```
for filename in os.listdir(my_dir)
```

My files are numbered incrementally, like `out1, out2, ...,out10, out11, ...`. Unfortunately, iteration over the files using the above command results in `out1, out10, out11` instead of `out1, out2, out3, ...`. It might be correct from file system point of view, but **semantically** wrong.

How can we get the right output?

Comment: @EugenePrimako I don't think this question is a duplicate of that but it definitely could help from the solutions of that answer. Maybe I misunderstand the use of duplicate on this site?

Comment: The questions are different. The other question is describing a slightly different sorting.

Comment: @TinaJ: no, it does not. Applying the code in the answers *will* show your required result.

Comment: @TinaJ I can't see the difference.  Could you be specific?

Comment: @Cole I got some insights from the other question and resolved the issue. Thanks.